# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pippi'

Tags: python

I am trying [this](https://www.codewars.com/kata/52a112d9488f506ae7000b95/train/python) kata in Codewars and I am passing all test cases but facing a strange error. 
My solution is

```
def is_int_array(arr):
    #your code here
    if type(arr) == type(list()):
        return not False in list(map(lambda a:False if a==None else(True if a==int(a) else False),arr))
    else:
        return False
```

and error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
    Test.assert_equals(is_int_array(arr),sol(arr),"It should work for random inputs too")
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 4, in is_int_array
    return not False in list(map(lambda a:False if a==None else(True if a==int(a) else False),arr))
  File "/home/codewarrior/solution.py", line 4, in <lambda>
    return not False in list(map(lambda a:False if a==None else(True if a==int(a) else False),arr))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pippi'
```

I can not debug this error and what is the reason for this error. Thanks

Comment: What are you passing into the function?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. What do you understand from that error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did it, and it's because you're not taking into account that the elements of the list can be strings.

In fact, the list elements can be anything, and the input can be a string or None instead of a list.

- None
- []
- "hello"
- [False, 1]
- ["hi", 3.0]
- etc.

are all possible inputs

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are passing as argument an array with one or more values, but one of the values of this array is 'pippi'.

The problem is that you can't convert a string to an int value. So, convert 'pippi' like the `is_int_array` function is doing in lambda expression `int(a)` will not work.